# Command line ELIZA chatbot

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an implementation of the classic [ELIZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) AI chat program that can be used on Ubuntu? I am looking for an ELIZA that can be used from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package search on [Repology](https://repology.org/projects/?search=ELIZA) went us to [`libchatbot-eliza-perl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libchatbot-eliza-perl) Ubuntu package.

You can install it using commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libchatbot-eliza-perl
```

and then play with it

> ```
> $ /usr/share/doc/libchatbot-eliza-perl/examples/simple
>
> Welcome to your therapy session.
> Your therapist's name is Liz.
>
> Liz:   Please tell me what's been bothering you. 
> you:   Cats
> Liz:   Does talking about this bother you?
> you:   Yes
> Liz:   I understand.
> you:   They are meawing.
> Liz:   Are you positive they are meawing?
> you:   Yes
> Liz:   Please go on.
> you:
> ```

It is Perl module, so you can read its source at `/usr/share/perl5/Chatbot/Eliza.pm` and `man Chatbot::Eliza.3pm` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man3/Chatbot::Eliza.3pm.html).